# Dont run the php srcipt again if its already running

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, singleton

I am reading data from the sheet and want to implement singleton in my process so that I can run read function, one at a time. but i got to know that i cant do that with singleton so how can i do that without using mutex or semaphore.

I have written a code for the same which calls the class and set a static variable and then call the function to check if it has the class, so if the class is there then don't run the read function.

```
class DataParser extends config {

   private static $_instance = false;

   public static
   function getInstance() {
    if (self::$_instance == false) {
     print_r("expression");
     self::$_instance = true;
     return self::$_instance;

    }
    return false;
   }

   function __construct($params) {}
}

$dataParser = new DataParser($confData);
$p = DataParser::getInstance();
if ($p) {
   $res = $dataParser - > read();

}
```

I want to run the read function one at a time, if one read is running then the other read will not run using php dont want to use mutex or semaphore

Comment: Are you using a database in your app? Is the reader task running in a distributed environment or always on the same server? I suggest looking into advisory locking. Both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html) and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) supports it.

Comment: i am reading google sheet so if the ready or writing is going on then it will not run the script again and dont want to use locking

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a database in your app? Is the reader task running in a distributed environment or always on the same server? I suggest looking into advisory locking. Both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html) and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) supports it.

It would look something like this using an exclusive lock on file in PHP.

```
class DataParser extends config {

   private static $_instance = false;

   public static
   function getInstance() {
    if (self::$_instance == false) {
     print_r("expression");
     self::$_instance = true;
     return self::$_instance;

    }
    return false;
   }

   function __construct($params) {}
}


$dataParser = new DataParser($confData);
$p = DataParser::getInstance();

$fp = fopen("/tmp/.lock", "r+");

if ($p && flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  
    $res = $dataParser->read();
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    
} else {
    // Skip silently or do something else?
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an empty file once the script is launched, and before this you check if this file exists.
And at the end of your script you delete it.